# how to launch R in anaconda PowerShell prompt in windows

Tags: python, r, powershell, anaconda

I am trying to launch a R terminal like python terminal shown below in anaconda powershell in windows 10. Somehow it seems like when I type r/R its simply re-running previous command. Anyway to do this?

```
PS C:\Users\user_p> conda activate base
(base) PS C:\Users\user_p> python
Python 3.8.8 (default, Apr 13 2021, 15:08:03) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

(base) PS C:\Users\user_p> conda deactivate
PS C:\Users\user_p> conda activate r_env
(r_env) PS C:\Users\user_p> r
conda activate r_env
(r_env) PS C:\Users\user_p> R
conda activate r_env
(r_env) PS C:\Users\user_p>
```

Comment: You're invoking `r` from PowerShell, where it is an alias for `Invoke-History` and by default recalls the most recently submitted command. A simple way to bypass the alias (on Windows) is to use `r.exe` for invocation. Alternatively, add `Remove-Alias r` to your PowerShell `$PROFILE` file to remove the alias on session startup. In general, in the case of name collisions, PowerShell aliases, functions, and cmdlets have higher precedence than external programs such as `R.exe`; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50191499/45375) to the linked duplicate.